# How to display data from mysql using condition date NOW

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

There any one know how to implementation my sql code using data record

```
SELECT * 
FROM `jadwal` 
WHERE YEAR(tgl) = YEAR(NOW()) 
  AND MONTH(tgl) = MONTH(NOW()) 
  AND DAY(tgl) = DAY(NOW())
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for. Are you asking how you would write this code in codeigniter?

Comment: yes correct i need to write my code into codeignitier

Comment: hope fully i found $this->db->where('YEAR(b.tgl) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(b.tgl) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(b.tgl) = DAY(NOW())'); thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows -

```
$where = array('YEAR(tgl)' => YEAR(NOW()), 
               'MONTH(tgl)' => MONTH(NOW()),
               'DAY(tgl)' => DAY(NOW())
              );
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get('jadwal');
$res1 = $query->result(); // as object
$res2 = $query->result_array(); // as array
```

try and let me know.